# How to debug `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE `testphp` 
( 
     `id`     INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `id`     NUMERIC(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `name`   VARCHAR(255), 
     `email`  VARCHAR(255), 
     `mobile` NUMERIC(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `image`  VARCHAR(255), 
     `gender` VARCHAR(255), 
     `day`    VARCHAR(255), 
     `status` ENUM('0', '1'), 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Comment: Rename the second column of Id. Varchar255 for gender?

Comment: Although the problem is clear after reading your code, you should add some description to it.

Comment: Pro tip 1: there's no need to add `please help me` or any variant to your questions, it sounds like begging. Pro tip 2: do add some text to your question to explain what you have done to resolve the problem. In this case, the error is rather self-explanatory - can you work out what "duplicate column name" might be pointing to? Pro tip 3: do format code in your questions, rather than leaving other people to do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have two columns called `id` in your `create table` statement. Either rename one of them:

```
CREATE TABLE `testphp`(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `another_id` NUMERIC(60) DEFAULT NULL, -- Here!
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    `email` VARCHAR(255),
    `mobile` NUMERIC(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `image` VARCHAR(255),
    `Gender` VARCHAR(255),
    `Day` VARCHAR(255),
    `status` ENUM('0','1'),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Or just remove it if it isn't really necessary:

```
CREATE TABLE `testphp`(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    `email` VARCHAR(255),
    `mobile` NUMERIC(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `image` VARCHAR(255),
    `Gender` VARCHAR(255),
    `Day` VARCHAR(255),
    `status` ENUM('0','1'),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do actually have two columns named `id` in that SQL, try renaming one.